# Creating IDisposable object asynchronously causes program to lag on closing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, idisposable

I am attempting to create a composite object which wraps two IDispoable objects.  These objects control the connection between my PC and two pieces of hardware.  Normally these would be used inside a using block.  However, I wish to persist them inside the composite object.  The composite object is also IDispoable and it handles the clean-up of the two object it wraps by calling their dispose methods when it get disposed.

I am testing the code as I develop it with a C# console application.  If I create the two object synchronously using a method with the following form all works as expected:

```
public CompositeObject BulidSync()
{
    IDisposeableA objectA = factory.CreateA();
    ObjectA.DoSomthing();
    IDisposeableB objectB =  factory.CreateB();;
    return new CompositeObject(objectA, objectB);
}
```

Since creating both objects takes some time I would like to create the two wrapped objects asynchronously.  The program then functions as expected until it is finished.  There is a rather large delay (up to ~10sec) after the program executes its last action.  The async code looks like:

```
public CompositeObject BulidAsync()
{
    Task<CompositeObject> tsk = createAsync();
    return tsk.Result;
}

private async Task<CompositeObject> createAsync()
{
    Task<IDisposeableA> task_A = Task.Run(() =>
    { 
        IDisposeableA objectA = factory.CreateA();
        objectA.DoSomthing();
        return IDisposeableA;
    });

    Task<IDisposeableB> task_b = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return factory.CreateB();
    });

    Task[] tasks = new Task[2] { task_A, task_b};

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    IDisposeableA objectA = task_A.Result;
    IDisposeableB objectB = task_b.Result;
    return new CompositeObject(objectA, objectB);
}
```

I have stepped through the code and seen the dispose methods for the wrapped objects getting called.

Am I doing this right?  Is there something extra I need to do when disposing an object if I create it asynchronously?

Comment: Post the context (how you call this), is this Web/WPF/.... ?

Comment: You're offloading the creation to the threadpool and then you block synchronously until it completes. There's no reason to do any of these. Offloading isn't truly async as it's just using a different thread and waiting for that thread to complete synchronously makes offloading meaningless.

Comment: And there really is no reason why any of this would affect the Disposing.

Comment: I would be asking myself *"why is this taking 10 seconds just to initialize"*? A constructor (IMO) is something that should execute quickly in order to construct the object. Any connection that needs to be made to the hardware perhaps should be lazily done once you generate the first request to it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I call this in a console app